# Get JSON response in PHP using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Here is my code to call AJAX and get the response from another PHP file:

```
$.post('<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajax-script/',{pickup:pickup,dropoff:dropoff,km:km},
        function(data){
            $('#fare').html(data);
            $('#loading_spinner').hide();

        });
```

**ajaxscript.php file**

```
$jsonData = '{"fare":30580,"actual_distance":1519,"city":"Islamabad","status":true}';

$json = json_decode($jsonData,true);
echo $json['fare'];
```

This code gives me the **fare** at the time of `$('#fare').html(data);`

But I need to extract the city from JSON, too, and for this I added an extra line in ajaxscript.php:

```
echo $json['city'];
```

After doing this, it gives me **30580Islamabad**

How can I store these two values separately in JavaScript? I need them for future work.

Comment: You are doing everything backwards

Comment: i dont understand what you exactly meant ?

Comment: Pass whole json as a result.

Comment: Simply `echo $json;`

Comment: its now show the "Array" in output, now how can i store $json['city'] values in variable after it gets the response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing everything backwards

Your PHP should be

```
$jsonData = '{"fare":30580,"actual_distance":1519,"city":"Islamabad","status":true}';

//$json = json_decode($jsonData,true);
echo $jsonData;
```

As you already have a JSONString to send to your javascript.

Then your javascript will recieve a javascript object in the data parameter of

```
$.post( '<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajax-script/', 
          {pickup:pickup,dropoff:dropoff,km:km}, 
   function( data ) {
        $('#fare').html(data.fare);
        $('#city').html(data.city);
        $('#loading_spinner').hide();
}, "json");
```

Note the `"JSON"` at the end of the javascript to tell it to expect a JSON Object, it will then convert the JSONString to a javascript Object automatically for you so the `data` parameter will be an onbect

Comment: well that $jsonData is getting response from a web service, after using your code it gives me nothing in the output

Comment: exactly, you used array, but I am using web service and it gets me the response and I saved that response in $jsonData

Comment: Ah I see. So you can just pass that whole string as the echoed data. That already is a JSONString and needs no amendment

Comment: I amended the javascript to fits better with the way you were calling post in your code

Answer (score -1):

```
Add Special characters at the end of each value and in jquery, using jquery split, cut the variable and display

like below;

$jsonData = '{"fare":30580^^,"actual_distance":1519^^,"city":"Islamabad^^","status":true}';

$json = json_decode($jsonData,true);
echo $json['fare'];


in jquery

function(data){
var tdata = data.split("^^");
            $('#fare').html(tdata[0]);
            $('#loading_spinner').hide();

        });
```

Comment: $jsonData coming from a web service, I cant change the response

Comment: did the service getting the key value pairs or not?

Comment: i have added the response from service in my code $jsonData in ajaxscript file

Comment: that has got to be the worst idea since ashtrays on motor cycles